# How to set class name in table cell in python django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I am learning django. I have a simple model named customer. Here is my model:

```
class Year(models.Model):
    year = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.year

    def __str__(self):
        return self.year


class Customer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Product(models.Model):
    customer_name = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    year = models.ForeignKey(Year, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.score

    def __str__(self):
        return self.score
```

and view is:
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404, redirect
from .models import Customer, Product, Year

## views.py

```
def home(request):
    customers = Customer.objects.all()
    years = Year.objects.all().values_list('year', flat=True).asc() # List of year name 
    rows = []
    for year in years:
        row = [year] + [None] * len(customers) # Row with year in first column, and the rest init with same size of customers list
        for idx, customer in enumerate(customers):
            quantities = customer.product_set.filter(year__year=year).valu e_list('quantity', flat=True) # filter product by year. That can return multiple product !!! 
            row[idx + 1] = ' ,'.join(quantities) # create a string of quantities
        rows.append(row) # Add new row in our rows list
    context = {'customers': customer,
               'rows': rows}
    return render(request, 'customer.html', context)
```

template:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block customer %}
<div class="container">
  <h2>Players Table</h2>
  <p>Customer with Product</p>
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
          <th>Year/Product</th>
          {% for customer in customers %}
              <th>{{ customer.name }}</th>
          {% endfor %}
      </tr>
    </thead>
      <tbody>
        {% for row in rows %}
            <tr>
                {% for cell in row %}
                    <th class="">{{cell}}</th>
                {% endfor %}
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
      </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Now I want that in cell of each row , th will be class and return the customer name,just like
`<th class='Customer Name 1'> 454</th>`
Every cell of row will return customer name with product.
Please help me as early possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

considering format of display in template, you need to use list of dicts as follows:

**Views**

```
def home(request):
customers = Customer.objects.all()
years = Year.objects.all().values_list('year', flat=True).asc() # List of year name 
result= []
for year in years:
   row = {year: []} # Row with year as key
    for idx, customer in enumerate(customers):
        quantities = customer.product_set.filter(year__year=year).value_list('quantity', flat=True) # filter product by year. That can return multiple product !!! 
        row[year].append({customer: ' ,'.join(quantities)}) #  {'2017': [{'A': '2 ,2 ,3'}]}
    result.append(row) #  Create list of dicts  [{'2017': [{'A': '2 ,2 ,3'}, {'B': '2 ,2 ,3'}, {'C': '2 ,2 ,3'}]}, {'2016': [{'A': '2 ,2 ,3'}, {'B': '2 ,2 ,3'}, {'C': '2 ,2 ,3'}]}]

context = {'customers': customer, 'result': result}
return render(request, 'customer.html', context)
```

**Template:**

```
<tbody>
{% for data in result %}
    {% for year, cust_prod_data in data.items %}
        <tr>
            <th>{{year}}</th>
            {% for cust_prod in cust_prod_data %}
                {% for customer_name, prod_qty  in cust_prod.items %}
                    <th class="{{customer_name}}">{{prod_qty}}</th>
                {% endfor %}
            {% endfor %}
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
</tbody>
```

Comment: Thank you @hemraj. Just one edit is required, 
{% for customer_name, prod_qty  in cust_prod.items %}